# $scope.$watch is not working inside a tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a tab with a few selected buttons embedded:

```
<tab id="graphTab" heading="Graph">
    <div class="analyze-select centered">
            <br></br>
            <h4>Filter by period:</h4>
            From:
            <select ng-model="startQuarter" ng-options="quarter for quarter in quarters"></select>
            <select ng-model="startYear" ng-options="year for year in years"></select>
            To:
            <select ng-model="endQuarter" ng-options="quarter for quarter in quarters"></select>
            <select ng-model="endYear" ng-options="year for year in years"></select> 

            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="filterTime()">Filter</button>
    </div>
</tab>
```

My controller instead looks like the following:

```
$scope.startYear ='';
$scope.startQuarter = '';
$scope.endYear = '';
$scope.endQuarter = '';

$scope.$watch('startYear',function(){
    console.log('startYear has changed!');
});

$scope.$watch('endYear',function(){
    console.log('endYear has changed!');
});

$scope.$watch('startQuarter',function(){
    console.log('startQuarter has changed!');
});

$scope.$watch('endQuarter',function(){
    console.log('endQuarter has changed!');
});
```

Now although the same scheme works for other `select` buttons I have in my view it doesn't work for those embedded in a tab. The problem is that those variables in the scope are not "watched" and angular does not seem to register any change (that is, nothing is printed on the console when I select different values in the dropdown menu).
Does that depend on the `<tab>` or am I missing something else?

UPDATE:
So if I move the three `select`s outside the `<tab>` element `$watch` works again.
Why is the `<tab>` element a problem for `$watch`?

Comment: Does it `<tab>` getting constructed? is there a directive?

Comment: No no directive for the `<tab>`. Everything is coded in the html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the reason it doesn't work within tab is because tab gets its own scope. To fix, you can try using properties on an object model. For instance in your controller:

```
$scope.myData = {};
```

Then your HTML:

```
....
<select ng-model="myData.startQuarter" ng-options="quarter for quarter in quarters"></select>
....
```

And your watch:

```
$scope.$watch('myData.startYear', function () {
    //Your code here
});
```

I believe this should work as myData.startYear would be updated within your tab directive (I assume you are using UI bootstrap with angular).

What happens here is that myData is prototypically inherited from the parent scope (your controller) and can see the same property (startYear) on that object. When you use a primitive property directly on the model, it does not work the way you are expecting it to (but works the way it should). This [article about scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) is nice and explains this in a little more detail. This type of pattern is recommended in angular when using ng-model for scenarios like this one.